# 'User listings' reputation stats are confusing and appear inconsistent in behaviour

Tags: discussion, reputation

I noticed today browsing `Users` that reputation isn't been calculated on a rolling calendar and as such is quite odd. At first I thought it was a cache issue, but now I see otherwise.

I've been on User Experience Stack Exchange for less than a month and have 343 reputation, therefore I would have expected that whether choosing month, quarter, year or all it would display 343, as this is how much reputation I have earned in the last month/quarter/year, but this is not the case.

[image: Reputation this month]

Month, quarter and year all display a reputation of '21', which means it has set the month/quarter/year beginning the 1st January 2013. Wouldn't you expect it to be showing reputation gained in the last rolling quarter, month or year? Normally I wouldn't roll over the reputation, the label 'reputation this month' maybe does suggest the cut, but I don't think most people even see this label.

Further more, what is strange is if you click 'week' it provides me a reputation of '41', so in this instance it is taking count as of Sunday 30th December 2012. Not conforming to the 2013 cut off, nor a rolling week, neither a conventional Monday - Sunday week.

[image: Reputation this week]

The behaviour seems inconsistent between selecting week and month, and I'm not sure it's what users expect...at least it's not what I expected.

Either way I think the fact that it reads a reputation that is higher "this week" than "this month", while technically it might be true, it doesn't sound correct [to me] (maybe others differ on this).

Comment: There is a related post on this over on the main meta.StackOverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/week-is-not-a-useful-default-for-the-users-page

Comment: Sunday to Saturday weeks are not entirely uncommon (they have a religious source rather than adhering to the ISO standard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally a **rolling period** is referred to as **past 30 days** or **past 7 days** and such. **Past month** would mean a **calendar month**.

Regarding user expectation, a tooltip is currently displayed on mouse hover which shows the actual starting date.

[image]

I am not saying it is good or bad but options are made available to user to see the actual time period (which is always a good user experience).

Comment: Nice find. I didn't even know about the tooltip until you posted this.

Comment: Same, didn't see this before. Still not sure if it's the right behaviour. Shame you can't conduct polls within Meta.

Comment: @slawrence10 Stack Exchange voting system (upvotes/downvotes) is a kind of a polling mechanism on meta sites.